# Propuesta: No hacer preguntas del tipo "¿Es posible ...?"

Tags: discusión, propuesta-de-faq

En el sitio principal a veces se ven preguntan que rezan: "¿Es posible ...?".

Bueno, todos sabemos que en el mundo de la programación absolutamente todo es posible. Realmente no tiene sentido preguntar eso puesto que la respuesta es: sí.

Dicho esto, propongo que agreguemos a la sección de [¿Qué preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) unas líneas como las siguientes:

> Por favor, no preguntes si algo es posible. En el mundo de la programación la respuesta siempre es que sí. Este tipo de preguntas suelen ser cerradas.
>
> En la mayoría de los casos alguien ya escribió una librería que hace lo que necesitas. Sino, puede que tengas que ser el primero en escribir una.

Comment: Vivimos en el mundo de chatGPT. A estas alturas SOes debería tener un bot que vaya leyendo la pregunta y haciendole sugerencias al OP. Pero no, seguimos como si fuera el siglo XX: actualizando el README.

Comment: Igual respaldo la buena intención de la propuesta.

Comment: @CandidMoe hablando del chatGPT le hice una pregunta muy amplia como muchas de las que aparecen en el sitio y me dio orientación, pasos a seguir para implementar lo que quería, tecnologías etc. Es increíble lo útil que puede ser, si quiero hacer una pregunta amplia del tipo 'como puedo crear un chat con html css js y express' te da lujo de detalles, alternativas, enfoques etc.

Comment: Las preguntas *¿Es posible...?* siempre van acompañadas de un autor perezoso que no investigo o no ha leído la documentación... el bot de comunidad deberia de cerrrar estas preguntas automaticamente ... si el OP tiene interes en mejorarla entonces se puede hacer la evaluacion y la excepcion para su re-apertura ... estoy de acuerdo con la propuesta.

Comment: `En el mundo de la programación la respuesta siempre es "depende"`

Comment: En el mundo de la programación latina la respuesta siempre es "Si lo puedes imaginar lo puedes programar".... QEPD

Comment: Muchas veces las preguntas están mal formuladas, en general las preguntas "Es posible...?" en realidad están preguntando "Como hacer que..". Yo busqué preguntas con el criterio "es posible" y la verdad es que encontré muchas de lo más interesantes.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Hacer eso creo que va en contra del sitio pues eliminas una pregunta sin ser evaluada siquiera.

Comment: Como adjetivo **Posible** significa `"Que puede ser o suceder, o que puede realizarse"`. Recordemos que SOes recibe visitas de muchos países, en base a eso en algunos de ellos se tiende a preguntar con cierta pena o recelo, y en vez de preguntar **¿Cómo hago esto?** se pregunta **¿Es posible hacer esto?**.  
En base a ello yo creo que mas que el titulo **Es posible...** lo mejor que podemos hacer, por el momento, es ver que la pregunta esté bien estructurada en base a los criterios del sitio...

Comment: @DanielBriceño hay una gran diferencia entre cerrar y eliminar ... valida estos conceptos.

Comment: Yo tengo experiencia. Hubo una pregunta que decía "es posible hacer x", entonces comenté "si, es posible. Pero fuera de joda, cual sería la verdadera pregunta", El OP respondió "¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?" después dije cosas que no vienen a la cuestion.

Comment: Yo apoyo la noción, por que si la pregunta es "¿es posible?", generalmente viene sin investigación. Solo podemos decir "sí" y dejarle el resto al OP. Pero la verdadera pregunta es "¿Cómo lo hago?" lo cual es muy amplio y, como siempre digo, nosotros no damos tutorías. Yo digo que tenemos que enlistanegrar "es posible" en los titulos de las preguntas.

Comment: Edit: leí una respuesta y ahora creo que solamente deberían de aparecer en las colas de revisión

Comment: @DanteS.  mira esta pregunta: [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/580711/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-manera-correcta-de-trabajar-con-ramas-en-git) aparte de ser un "¿Cómo lo hago?", es un Off-Topic del sitio ... pero ha tenido buena recepcion y no es muy amplia como supones ...

Comment: Me expresé mal. Quise decir que en la mayoría de los casos de esas preguntas, suele no haber investigación por parte del OP.

Comment: La mayoría de las preguntas que "molestan", son formuladas por usuarios nuevos... **ningún recien llegado lee el recorrido**, aceptenlo, puede gustarnos o no, pero es la realidad, es nuestro trabajo (autoimpuesto), ir formándolos para que vayan mejorando la calidad de sus preguntas, y no con votos negativos (que están desaconsejados por el sitio), sino con los comentarios, que dicho sea de paso, están para eso, y no para responder preguntas como hacemos varios de nosotros. leer sobre votos negativos 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down.

Comment: Con respecto a las respuestas en los comentarios, y hablo por mi, cuando la respuesta no es un trozo de código sino una sugerencia, o algo parecido, evito la zona de respuestas (a pesar de que este tipo de respuestas están avaladas por el sitio), para evitar los votos negativos, pero sobre todo para no tener que responder a los **"defensores de aquello que desconozco"**, que la verdad, me molestan más que cualquier tipo de pregunta. leer en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer **contesta la pregunta**.

Comment: leer en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down **¿Cuándo debo votar negativo?** y **¿Cuáles son las alternativas al voto negativo?**.

Answer (score 15):

Yo no tengo ningún problema con que la gente pregunte si las cosas son o no posibles, no solo de gente con muchísima experiencia, sino incluso de aquellas personas advenedizas. De hecho creo que es uno de los grandes tesoros de tener un junior en tu equipo, que pregunta si es posible hacer algunas cosas.

Mi experiencia participando en comunidades de programación no ha sido tan grata debido a que la gente especialmente en latinoamérica tiene demasiados sesgos y prejuicios que nos impiden colaborar en proyectos grandes pero la razón por la que sigo participando en más de 100 comunidades de programación es por los novatos, porque con su candidez preguntan cosas que a otros les enojan y a mí me asombra cada vez que veo que se puede lograr.

Considero a esta candidez una fuente ilimitada de creatividad, una manera de limar asperezas y de quitarnos esas etiquetas que tanto daño nos hacen, nos vuelve humildes ya que nos puede hacer que nos demos cuenta de nuestra insignificancia.

Algunos ejemplos de esto que podría dar son:

- como correr windows en mi navegador

y por dar un ejemplo hay cosas como esta: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows95

- como escribir un hola mundo solamente con p*nes y javascript:

ya se que es clickbait, pero se puede:

```
let greet = function(){
var D="8"
,PENiS=("PENIS".length^(((((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)|(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D)))*(((((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D))
,penis=(((((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))
,PeNiS=(("8================D".length/((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)))|(((((((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D)))+(8==D|8==D)
,PEnis=""
,PENIS=(((PENiS*((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)))-((penis*penis)+penis)/penis)^((PeNiS*penis)-(penis*penis)+(((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))))
,PENIs=PENIS+(PENIS^((penis*penis)-((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))))
,pENIS=PENIS+penis
,PEnIS=(PeNiS<<(8==D|8==D))|((penis*((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)))+(((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D)))
,PenIS=((PENiS+PeNiS)^((penis+(((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D)))*((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))))
,PENis=PENIs-(8===D|(((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D)))
,PeniS=(8===D)&(8===D)
,PeNIs=PeNiS|(8==D|8==D)
,pEnIs=PENIs&(penis*((((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D)))+(8==D|8==D))
,peNIS=[pENIS,PENIS,PenIS,PEnIS,PeNIs,PENiS,PeNiS,PENIs,PENis]
,penIS=[(((8!==D)|(8==D^8==D))<<((8==D|8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)))|(8==D|8==D),(8==D)|(8==D^8==D),((((8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)|(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D)),((((8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)|(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D)),(8===D)|(8==D^8==D),((((8==D)|(8==D^8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D),(((8==D)|(8==D^8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D),(8===D)|(8==D^8==D),((8==D)|(8==D^8==D))<<(8==D|8==D),((((8==D)<<(8==D|8==D)|(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))|(8==D|8==D)),(((((8==D)|(8==D^8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D)),((((8==D)|(8==D^8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))<<(8==D|8==D))];
for(;;){if(PeniS>=pEnIs){break;}
PEnis=PEnis+String.fromCharCode(peNIS[penIS[PeniS]]);PeniS++}
return PEnis.toLowerCase();
}
```

- como correr java en el navegador sin el plugin de java

halle cosas como teavm y bck2browsr

- como hacer mi interfaz en un JFrame con HTML en vez de swing

alli puedes encontrar cosas como dukescript y si... este si es bait, ve a dukescript.com este framework fue premiado por Oracle

otra cosa que aprendí con ese tipo de cosas es que css es turing complete, lo que quiere decir que si deseas hacer un motor de juegos en css o lo que se te ocurra puedes hacerlo con tiempo y recursos infinitos

y si quieres un ejemplo de este sitio:

[¿Es posible envolver un ejecutable en un Frame de Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70036/es-posible-envolver-un-ejecutable-en-un-frame-de-java)

y antes de seguiros atiborrando con ejemplos pasemos a los...

### Argumentos

- Nos ayudará a flexibilizar las reglas de la comunidad para no convertirnos en soen
- El hecho de que seamos SOes habla ya de que nuestro ingenio y subnormalidad son bienvenidos
- Nos ayudará a evitar el estancamiento que nos afecta a muchos programadores en cierto momento de nuestra vida
- Si la proporción de estas preguntas aumenta y sabemos manejarlo... podrá atraer a programadores súper experimentados
- Nos ayudará a evitar la cultura de la funación es decir el fascismo, la cancelación de las personas que no son como nosotros y no piensan como nosotros
- Nos ayudará a mejorar el problema de cultura, ya que nos quitará de estar a la defensiva de sobajar a otros por hacer preguntas aparentemente simples o imposibles, de las votaciones negativas en cadena, etc
- Serán una maravilla en el futuro con el advenimiento de los datos estructurados, ya que permitirán a bots responder ese mismo tipo de preguntas para nosotros, ya sabes

> Sirila como puedo hacer un sistema operativo para controlar mi podadora desde el celular si tengo un arduino uno y solo se javascript a nivel basico

> Segun el sitio stack overflow en español debes seguir los siguientes pasos: ....

Personalmente prefiero las preguntas de tipo "es posible X" en vez de las "urgente ayuda con X" empezando por la actitud de quien pregunta

Comment: Algo que podemos hacer de intermedio, es que el sistema automaticamente ponga a las preguntas que contienen "es posible" en las colas de revisión. Ya que como dije, preguntas que empiezan con eso, suelen carecer de investigación y ser muy amplias.

Comment: seria mejor usar el asistente de preguntas y agregarle la casilla de verificacion "ya lo he intentado o lo he investigado antes"

Comment: Eso sirve también, no son excluyentes. Ten en cuenta que a los que no les importe, estén urgidos, etc van a tildar la casilla de verificación solo para poder publicar. Además, ya [es lo primero que dice como preguntar](/help/how-to-ask). La comunidad debe revisar de todas formas. Sin embargo, tu idea ayudaría a reducir la cantidad de gente que viene sin haberlo intentado primero.

Comment: Aunque hay algo mal en el centro de ayuda. Para la comunidad, buscar en google cuenta como buscar e investigar. Y como preguntar dice que busques dentro del sitio. Yo lo cambiaría a algo mas acertado.

Comment: El primer problema con el enfoque es suponer que quién pregunta sabrá entender la respuesta.

Comment: @CandidMoe ese es mas bien un problema de toda comunicación humana

Answer (score -3):

Sinceramente yo creo que no se tendría que prohibir ese tipo de preguntas ya que aun que es cierto que no han investigado todo lo que deberían hay muchas veces que novatos no saben como explicar de forma correcta su pregunta y si le borramos su pregunta diciéndole que infringe una regla se va a desanimar y aparte que empeorara la reputación de esta pagina web aun que es cierto que con mucha paciencia se puede lograr programar todo pero no hay librerías de todo y comprended que un novato no se va a poner a trabajar en una librería nueva por ello yo creo que si se detecta que a usado '¿Es posible?' seria mejor primero aconsejarle que investigue mas metiéndose en paginas oficiales y segundo aconsejarle que pregunte '¿Existe una librería para?'

Comment: Mi idea no es prohibir que pregunten. Sino que dejen de usar títulos del tipo "¿Es posible?" por títulos más descriptivos.

Comment: Eso ultimo no estoy de acuerdo. Uno de los motivos de cierre es que está pidiendo recomendaciones de librerias y otros recursos externos. Mas allá de que esto se haga cumplir o no, el sitio no está diseñado para opiniones.

Comment: Si quiere preguntarle a quien sea algo, tiene que aprender a explicarse. Si no transmite bien la idea, no se puede dar una buena respuesta. Sobre las reglas, bueno, vivimos en sociedad, hay normas nos guste o no. Tienen que leerlas y adaptarse a ellas. El que estas reglas estén bien escritas, es algo aparte.

Comment: Por cierto, solo recomendación, sin animo de ofender. No olvides usar puntos y comas. Yo, al menos, leo decorrido y no capto del todo el mensaje cuando no estan los signos de puntuación.